# Github Actions detect author_association

Tags: github, github-api, github-actions

So I've been working on a couple of projects using Github Actions, and have come across PullApprove which is able to get the `author_association` from somewhere and use it. I'd like to setup some commands, which are restricted to `author_association == collaborators`, but am unsure how to go about this. Any advice would be appreciated.

Some code if you want it:

```
name: Command Management

on:
  issue_comment:
    types: [created, edited]

jobs:
  # Automatically reverts commits on request
  revert-commit:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    if: contains(github.event.comment.body, '/revert')
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2.3.1
      - name: Automatic Revert
        uses: srt32/revert@v0.0.1
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

Comment: If you are open to other solutions, [slash-command-dispatch](https://github.com/peter-evans/slash-command-dispatch) can be configured to only allow collaborators with `write` access to execute slash commands. That is actually the default.

Comment: Heya @peterevans. Thanks for the recommendation, I'm defiantly going to consider it as it looks like a good alternative. I've opened an issue with some requests

Answer (score 2):

For what it's worth, I can tell you that in PullApprove we use the [PR `author_assiciation` from the REST API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/pulls#get-a-pull-request). Looks like there is actually a similar thing for issue comments, but not in the REST API or webhook events -- I think you'd have to make a call to the GraphQL API to get that info (get the `node_id` for the issue comment off of the event and use that to make a call to GraphQL as a custom step in your action?): https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/reference/objects#issuecomment

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Michael, this is the best documentation I found:

> pull_request.author_association returns an item from
> CommentAuthorAssociation, which is one of the following:
>
> ```
> COLLABORATOR: Author has been invited to collaborate on the repository.
> CONTRIBUTOR: Author has previously committed to the repository.
> FIRST_TIMER: Author has not previously committed to GitHub.
> FIRST_TIME_CONTRIBUTOR: Author has not previously committed to the repository.
> MANNEQUIN: Author is a placeholder for an unclaimed user.
> MEMBER: Author is a member of the organization that owns the repository.
> NONE: Author has no association with the repository.
> OWNER: Author is the owner of the repository.
> ```

...

> When interacting with an organization's repo, the
> pull_request.author_association value is different depending on if the
> actor is an external collaborator, an org member, or neither.
>
> If the actor is neither an org member nor an external collaborator
> their author_association will be one of the following:

```
FIRST_TIMER: The actor has never contributed to any repository on GitHub before
FIRST_TIME_CONTRIBUTOR: The actor has never contributed to this repository before
CONTRIBUTOR: The actor has previously contributed to the repository
```

> If the actor has been added as an external collaborator, their author_association
> will be COLLABORATOR, no matter which set of permissions they’ve been
> given. If they have read permissions, they’re a COLLABORATOR. If they
> have admin permissions, they’re still a COLLABORATOR.
>
> Finally, if the actor is a member of the organization that owns the
> repository their author_association will be MEMBER. This is true
> whether they are an organization member or owner. In addition, their
> author_association will always be MEMBER regardless of the permissions
> they have on the repository. If they have read permissions, they’re a
> MEMBER. If they have admin permissions, they’re still a MEMBER.
>
> The only other state that you might be interested in is OWNER. This
> state is not possible with organization owned repositories. It is only
> returned when a repository is owned by a specific user.

...

See https://michaelheap.com/github-actions-check-permission/

Comment: That seems to be incorrect. I am an org member of a repo in which there's PR open in which I've posted a commend. The `echo ${{ github.event.comment.author_association }}` returned `CONTRIBUTOR`, where it should have returned `MEMBER` as I am a member of the org that owns the repository.